# Difference between random variables, random samples, and observations

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, sampling

Here there is my (difficult to be phrased without looking silly) question: is there an actual difference between a random variable, a random sample, and an observation?
*[For what below, the books I am reading are De Groot and Schervish's "Probability and Statistics" and Spiegel's "Statistics" (Schaum's)]*

Before jumping to the conclusion that I am missing some very basic stuff (which could be, of course), give me a second to explain my problem and read below the example, which could lead to a slightly more precise formulation of the question.

> **Example**
> Given a population of 100 students in a campus, we want to gather some information concerning their heights, such as mean, variance, etc. Thus, on Monday we get a sample of 5 students, on Tuesday we get a sample of other 5 students, and so on until Sunday: we end up having 7 samples, with 5 observations each.

In the example above, for what would we use the notation $X_i$?
I know that notation is just notation, but my point is that $X_i$ is used for many things in statistics and sometime I feel I lose sight of the actual object behind the notation.

What I mean is that, by taking the example, my first feeling is that the r.v. is the height, every student is an observation, and we have the 7 samples (this would be my feeling after reading Spiegel). But then, after De Groot and Schervish, I get the feeling that a student is a r.v. in its own right, call it, the $X_i$ random variable.

What above becomes even muddier to me when we move to flipping coins (a favourite example of books): if we flip one coin $n$ times and we do it $k$ times to get if it is fair, what is the r.v.?
I would say that we have just *one* r.v., which is the behavior of the coin; also, we have $k$ samples of the behavior of this one coin, with $n$ observations each. Thus, $X_i$ would be reserved for the sample?
However, it seems to me that quite often (always), one observation (say the $i$th) of a head or tail of that one coin is considered a r.v. in itself, thus getting the $X_i$ notation.

If you are wondering why this question, simply, I want to get this, because I have the feeling the confusion I have is hampering my possibility of gettings some things right in statistics.

---

Below, some links that - unfortunately - did not help me in getting this right:
[Random Variable vs data vs random sample](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853645/random-variable-vs-data-vs-random-sample)
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239500/what-is-the-difference-between-random-variable-and-random-sample

Concerning the second link, the comment of hanugm to the accepted answer (which has been left unanswered) really summarizes what my problem is all about.

Comment: To the moderators: Please, migrate the question to stats.stackexchange if you feel this is not the right place where to ask it, or if you think there are better chances to get an answer there. Thanks as always for the support.